# How to simulate keyboard right click with java robot class

Tags: java, automation, awtrobot, key-events

I am trying to simulate right click event using java robot class. but here my problem is I should use keyboard right click button, but not mouse right click(`InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK`). Can any one suggest how I can do this?